# Run is slow between components in Test Lab

Tags: hp-uft, alm

I'm using UFT/BPT for API and GUI Testing, everything works fine, I have business components which are in flows which are used in Business-Process, I run the Business-Process from Test Lab - ALM, here I have a problem with big times on runs.

**EX: Business-Process Test**

**Component 1:**

Start: 18:17:48

End: 18:17:48

**Component 2:**

Start: 18:18:00

End: 18:18:01

**Component 3:**

Start: 18:18:12

End: 18:18:13

**Component 4:**

Start: 18:18:24

End: 18:18:24

**Conclusion:**

After Component 1 it's ended and Component 2 it's started are 12 seconds between.

**Component 2 and Component 3:** 11 seconds

**Component 3 and component 4:** 11 seconds

Why it's stay so much between components?

Comment: You will need to include your sources.

Comment: You can also consider to ask this question on [Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, i just ask there this question. :)

Comment: >> i just ask there this question<< Where? Have a link? Would like to see the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same starting with UFT 15+, I got the official reply that since the new version has sooo many new powerful features it is to be considered normal for some things to take more time with the new version.

Which of course is not a good reply, but that´s what I have been officially told by my support source.

So if you have a short test calling 10 components which all need 2 seconds to do their job, you used to execute such test in 10*2=20 seconds, and now it will take 10*2+20*10=220 seconds. For that additional 0 (from 20 to about 200 seconds), you get absolutely nothing in return. Great deal? Oooookay...

I think this should be fixed, naturally. There is no good reason why calling a component should have an oberhead of 9-15 seconds (SECONDS!).

But what can you do if you are using standard software packages that get messed up by the devs over the years? You can waste your time with support, but you will achieve nothing. So what can you do?

Nothing, except for migrating elsewhere :(

And I think it´s a shame. I wish SO user Motti (ex-UFT dev) would see this and clarify, but, well, he cannot be everywhere :)